# How to write valid If clause inside select or write function

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, ssms, where-clause

I have procedure like this and I get error in **If** clause. I think it is because COUNT. But my clause have to be like that so I don't know how to solve it. Maybe it would be good to create a function or something similar.  Rest of the code is okay

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DohvatiSveUgovore @zavodId int
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempUgovori TABLE
    (
         Id int,
         UstrojstvenaJedinica nvarchar(100),
         VrstaUgovora nvarchar(100),
         KlasaUgovora nvarchar(100),
         UrudzbeniBrojUgovora nvarchar(100),
         DatumPocetkaUgovora nvarchar(10),
         DatumIstekaUgovora nvarchar(10)
    )

    INSERT INTO @TempUgovori(Id, UstrojstvenaJedinica, VrstaUgovora, KlasaUgovora, UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, DatumPocetkaUgovora, DatumIstekaUgovora)
        SELECT 
        u.Id,
        ISNULL(STRING_AGG(LTRIM(RTRIM(z.SkraceniNaziv)), ', '), '') AS 'UstrojstvenaJedinica',
        vu.Naziv AS 'VrstaUgovora',
        ISNULL(u.KlasaUgovora, '') AS 'KlasaUgovora',
        ISNULL(u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, '') AS 'UrudzbeniBrojUgovora',
        (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumPocetkaUgovora',
        (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumIstekaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumIstekaUgovora'
        FROM Ugovor AS u    
            LEFT JOIN VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica AS vuu
                ON u.Id = vuu.UgovorId
            INNER JOIN SifVrstaUgovora AS vu
                ON u.VrstaUgovoraId = vu.Id
            LEFT JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].hcphs.SifZavod AS z
                ON vuu.UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = z.Id                        

            if( (SELECT COUNT(UstrojstvenaJedinicaId)  FROM VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica WHERE UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS') = 1)  
            begin
            (SELECT *  FROM  VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica WHERE UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS')            
            end
            ELSE
            (SELECT * FROM  VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica WHERE  Isdeleted = 0  and UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = @zavodId)
            end
```

ERROR is here in Group by and I don't know why.

```
GROUP BY u.Id, vu.Naziv, u.KlasaUgovora, u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, u.DatumIstekaUgovora

            SELECT  
            tu.Id,
            tu.UstrojstvenaJedinica AS 'UstrojstvenaJedinica',
            tu.VrstaUgovora AS 'VrstaUgovora',
            tu.KlasaUgovora AS 'KlasaUgovora',
            tu.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora AS 'UrudzbeniBrojUgovora',
            tu.DatumIstekaUgovora AS 'DatumPocetkaUgovora',
            tu.DatumIstekaUgovora AS 'DatumIstekaUgovora',
            ISNULL(STRING_AGG(LTRIM(RTRIM(p.Naziv)), ', '), '') as 'Partner'
            FROM @TempUgovori AS tu
                LEFT JOIN VezaUgovorPartner AS vup
                    on tu.Id = vup.UgovorId
                LEFT JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].dbo.Partner as p
                    ON vup.PartnerId = p.PartnerID

            GROUP BY tu.Id, tu.UstrojstvenaJedinica, tu.VrstaUgovora, tu.KlasaUgovora, tu.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, tu.DatumPocetkaUgovora, tu.DatumIstekaUgovora

        END


                EXEC [TEST_Ugovori_Prod].[dbo].[DohvatiSve] 6;  
                GO
```

I am sorry for too much code but without it I can't run query.

Comment: You can't just write `if (some criteria) select from this table` as that is not valid SQL.  What are you trying to achieve with that `if`?

Comment: Just write incorrect syntax near group by...

I have a couple of conditions in the if:

UstrojstvenaJedinicaId is not 0 AND that UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = @zavodId OR where UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = 10 and the count of such is exactly 1

Comment: That's my point, your use of an `if` is not valid SQL.  Are you trying to filter your dataset?  If so, you need a `where` clause, not an `if`

Comment: I tried with where and didn't succeed.  Can you write where clause with that:

Comment: Beacuse COUNT in where doesn't work for me

Comment: Because it is an aggregate.  Those need to be in a `having` clause.  More likely however, you would need to rearrange your query to not need it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to tell SQL Server to join to VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica differently depending on the circumstances. The sql engine can't figure that out. For a very brief discussion on how sql evaluates a query, here's a start:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries?forum=transactsql

Maybe something like this will work for you?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DohvatiSveUgovore @zavodId int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TempUgovori TABLE
(
     Id int,
     UstrojstvenaJedinica nvarchar(100),
     VrstaUgovora nvarchar(100),
     KlasaUgovora nvarchar(100),
     UrudzbeniBrojUgovora nvarchar(100),
     DatumPocetkaUgovora nvarchar(10),
     DatumIstekaUgovora nvarchar(10)
);

DECLARE @HCPHS integer;
SELECT 
  @HCPHS = COUNT(UstrojstvenaJedinicaId)  
FROM 
  VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica 
WHERE 
  UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS';

IF @HCPHS = 1
  INSERT INTO @TempUgovori(Id, UstrojstvenaJedinica, VrstaUgovora, KlasaUgovora, UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, DatumPocetkaUgovora, DatumIstekaUgovora)
      SELECT 
      u.Id,
      ISNULL(STRING_AGG(LTRIM(RTRIM(z.SkraceniNaziv)), ', '), '') AS 'UstrojstvenaJedinica',
      vu.Naziv AS 'VrstaUgovora',
      ISNULL(u.KlasaUgovora, '') AS 'KlasaUgovora',
      ISNULL(u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, '') AS 'UrudzbeniBrojUgovora',
      (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumPocetkaUgovora',
      (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumIstekaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumIstekaUgovora'
      FROM Ugovor AS u    
          LEFT JOIN VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica AS vuu
              ON u.Id = vuu.UgovorId
          INNER JOIN SifVrstaUgovora AS vu
              ON u.VrstaUgovoraId = vu.Id
          LEFT JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].hcphs.SifZavod AS z
              ON vuu.UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = z.Id                        
          <JOIN OF SOME KIND>
          (SELECT *  FROM  VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica WHERE UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS')            
            ON <SOME CRITERIA>
      GROUP BY u.Id, vu.Naziv, u.KlasaUgovora, u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, u.DatumIstekaUgovora
ELSE
  INSERT INTO @TempUgovori(Id, UstrojstvenaJedinica, VrstaUgovora, KlasaUgovora, UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, DatumPocetkaUgovora, DatumIstekaUgovora)
      SELECT 
      u.Id,
      ISNULL(STRING_AGG(LTRIM(RTRIM(z.SkraceniNaziv)), ', '), '') AS 'UstrojstvenaJedinica',
      vu.Naziv AS 'VrstaUgovora',
      ISNULL(u.KlasaUgovora, '') AS 'KlasaUgovora',
      ISNULL(u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, '') AS 'UrudzbeniBrojUgovora',
      (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumPocetkaUgovora',
      (SELECT ISNULL(convert(varchar(10), u.DatumIstekaUgovora, 104), '')) AS 'DatumIstekaUgovora'
      FROM Ugovor AS u    
          LEFT JOIN VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica AS vuu
              ON u.Id = vuu.UgovorId
          INNER JOIN SifVrstaUgovora AS vu
              ON u.VrstaUgovoraId = vu.Id
          LEFT JOIN [TEST_MaticniPodaci2].hcphs.SifZavod AS z
              ON vuu.UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = z.Id                        
          <JOIN OF SOME KIND>
          (SELECT * FROM  VezaUgovorUstrojstvenaJedinica WHERE  Isdeleted = 0  and UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = @zavodId)
            ON <SOME CRITERIA>
      GROUP BY u.Id, vu.Naziv, u.KlasaUgovora, u.UrudzbeniBrojUgovora, u.DatumPocetkaUgovora, u.DatumIstekaUgovora
```